# Backup a Windows PC to a Linux Machine

Tags: ubuntu, backup, windows, rsync

What is a good backup strategy to backup a Windows 7 box to a Ubuntu box that are on the same network?

The solution I am thinking would be to mount a Windows folder to Ubutnu then use `rsync`. But I'm new at this, so that might not be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[Delta copy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) is a good tool that will allow you to do that.  Just make sure that the linux box has a visible share on the windows machine -- for example using samba.

Answer (score 1):

BackupPC would be an option.  It can also be used to backup Linux and other platforms.  I documented [my implementation](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/setting-up-backuppc-on-windows/).